# Socket.IO emitting the event on the wrong Session

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webrtc, videochat

Newbie programmer here.
Need some help on a mini-project for an ongoing job assessment.

The project is a Video Chat application that uses JavaScript, Socket.IO, and WebRTC concepts.
The socket.id is being used as some sort of unique code to connect to other users / sessions.

I have 2 sessions of the application open for testing purposes.

The feature being tested is the "Reject" button, when one user (session) tries to connect another.

**Scenario: (Session A tries to connect with Session B)**
It doesn't matter if the type of request is Video Call or Chat, when I click the "Reject" button, it seems like socket.io is emitting the event on Session B (the same session that's given a choice to either Accept/Reject the request), leaving Session A (the session that's trying to connect) stuck with a connection attempt dialog box.

**Screenshot during the connection attempt:**
[Session A attempting to connect to Session B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le0xa.png)
[Session B receives the incoming connection request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YclID.png)

**Screenshot of Session B rejecting the connection attempt**
[Session B receiving the dialog box that Session A should have received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3O77.png)
[Session A stuck on the connection attempt screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OZzS.png)

This is the link to my project repository:
[Meet-n-Greet Video Chat App](https://github.com/charanelgile/Meet-n-Greet)

I think the problem is coming from the function "sendPreOfferResponse()" from "webRTChandler.js"
[function "sendPreOfferResponse()" from "webRTChandler.js"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUVzH.png)
The structure of the data it passes is:

```
const data = {
  callerSocketId: connectedUserDetails.socketId,
  preOfferResponse,
};
```

But the variable "connectedUserDetails" was initially defined without any value. So in the event listener on "app.js", it is only receiving the data as:

```
const data = {
  preOfferResponse
};
```

I tried assigning "callerSocketId" key with the value of "socket.id", but it gets the socket.id of the current session, not the session that's trying to connect.
["callerSocketId" key assigned with the value of "socket.id"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptWZ8.png)

How can I get the specific socket.id of the session that's attempting to connect??